# How to convert a Java Enum to Typescript Enum

Tags: java, typescript, enums

I have an Enum in Java set up like so:

```
public enum ObjectType implements Serializable{

    TABLE(0,"TABLE"),
    VIEW(1,"VIEW");

    private int objectType;
    private String description; 
    private String sqlType;

    ObjectType(int objectType, String description, String sqlType) {
        this.objectType = objectType;
        this.description = description;
        this.sqlType = sqlType;
    }
}
```

and I want to set up an equivalent Typescript Enum and I've done so like this:

```
export enum ObjectType {
    TABLE,
    VIEW
}

export namespace ObjectType {

    export function getType(description : string): ObjectType {
        if(description.toUpperCase() === "TABLE") {
            return ObjectType.TABLE;
        } else if(description.toUpperCase() === "VIEW") {
            return ObjectType.VIEW;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    export function getObjectType(objectType: ObjectType): string {
        switch(objectType) {
            case ObjectType.TABLE:
                return "TABLE";
            case ObjectType.VIEW:
                return "VIEW";
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, can I create a constructor function which has a description and sqlType in Typescript as well?

Comment: Did you read https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html?

Comment: Yea thats where I got the idea for my initial enum configuration. but I am still confused as to how to add a sqlType and description field to this enum. In Java you can specify a constructor which contains additional fields. Can you mimic that behavior in Typescript enums?

Comment: From the link it is clear that you can not do that. enum in Typescript is just an alias for integers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure if you can do that with typescript enums, but something along these lines should work:

```
class MyEnum{

  public static readonly ONE=new MyEnum(1, "Single-Digit");
  public static readonly TWO=new MyEnum(200, "Multi-Digit");

  public readonly index: number
  public readonly type: string

  private constructor(index:number, type: string){
    this.index=index;
    this.type=type;
  }
}
```

From what I can tell, typescript enums basically translate to numbers, so this may be the only way.